# Can I conclude that my group is finitely generated, if it is a homomorphic image of a free-group on finitely many generators?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, finitely-generated, combinatorial-group-theory

Say $X$ is a finite set, $F \langle X \rangle$ is the free group on the set $X$ and $G$ be a group.

If I have a surjective homomorphism $$\varphi : F \langle X \rangle\longrightarrow G$$ then can I conclude that $G$ is finitely generated?

Comment: Some might regard that as the **definition** of finitely-generated group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can conclude that if $x_1,\dots ,x_n$ are elements of $X$, $\phi(x_1),\dots,\phi(x_n)$ are generators of $G$. Let $g\in G$, $g=\phi(u)$ where $u$ is an element of $F(X)$, you can write $u=x_{i_1}^{n_1}\dots x_{i_p}^{n_p}$ where $i_j\in\{1,\dots ,n\}$. This implies that $$g=\phi(u)=\phi(x_{i_1})^{n_1}\dots\phi(x_{i_p})^{n_p}.$$

Comment: Thanks man. I am totally embarassed. I don't know why I kept forgetting that my X is finite. I kept thinking that every group is a homomorphic image of a free group and if I had this, I would have that every group is finitely generated. But I forgot that X if finite.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since $F\langle X\rangle/ \operatorname{ker}\varphi \cong G$, by the first isomorphism theorem,  and every quotient of a finitely generated group is finitely generated.